# Cardiovascular Risk Calculator

Tags: probability

The American College of Cardiology has a risk calculator for the probability of a cardiovascular event within a 10 year time frame based on various risk factors. See the calculator here. http://tools.acc.org/ASCVD-Risk-Estimator-Plus/#!/calculate/estimate/

If the calculation determines the probability is 10% or higher within this 10 year timeframe, statins are recommended.

My question: how to convert the 10% 10 year probability to an annual probability over the 10 year timeframe?

Comment: It depends on whether two or more cardiovascular events are possible, and whether having one changes the later probability of the next one

Answer (score 0):

We can make the assumption that cardiovascular events are independent and that the probability of having one in a given year stays constant, say $x$. Then having 10% prob of having at least one is the same as having 90% prob of not having any. 
So we can solve $(1-x)^{10} = 0.9$, so $x = 1-0.9^{\frac{1}{10}}$, so, which is about 1.05%.